# Tornado: Running both websocket and flash policy server on port 80

Tags: python, actionscript-3, websocket, tornado

I want to run both a websocket and a flash policy file server on port 80 using Tornado. The reason for not wanting to run a server on the default port 843 is that it's often closed in corporate networks. Is it possible to do this and if so, how should I do this?

I tried the following structure, which does not seem to work: the websocket connection works, but the policy file request is not routed to the `TCPHandler`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.gen
from tornado.options import define, options

from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer


define("port", default=80, help="run on the given port", type=int) 

class FlashPolicyServer(TCPServer):

    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        self._stream = stream
        self._read_line()

    def _read_line(self):
        self._stream.read_until('\n', self._handle_read)

    def _handle_read(self, data):
        policyFile = ""
        self._stream.write(policyFile)
        self._read_line()


class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        pass

    def on_close(self):
        pass


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    mainLoop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    app = tornado.web.Application(
        handlers=[
            (r"/websocket", WebSocketHandler),
            (r"/", FlashPolicyServer)
        ], main_loop=mainLoop
    )

    httpServer = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    httpServer.listen(options.port)

    mainLoop.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any ideas? If this is not possible, would another idea be to serve the policy file via port 443?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your approach:

1. TCPServer is used like this:

   server = TCPServer()
   server.listen(6666)
   IOLoop.instance().start()

   That would do the trick, after you remove the `(r"/", FlashPolicyServer)` line.

   But you want to use port 80.
2. However, you can't do that, because you need to have another HTTP server at that port.

So what you can do is to use `nginx` and set up port 80 as reverse proxying for `/websocket`, serving a Flash policy file otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by monkey-patching IOStream and HTTPServer:

```
def prepend_to_buffer(self, chunk):
    self._read_buffer.appendleft(chunk)
    self._read_buffer_size += len(chunk)
    if self._read_buffer_size >= self.max_buffer_size:
        logging.error("Reached maximum read buffer size")
        self.close()
        raise IOError("Reached maximum read buffer size")
    return len(chunk)

def first_data_handler(self, data):
    if data == '<policy-file-request/>\0':
        self.stream.write(policy_file + '\0')
    else:
        self.stream.prepend_to_buffer(data)
        tornado.httpserver.HTTPConnection(self.stream, self.address, self.request_callback,self.no_keep_alive, self.xheaders)

def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
    self.stream = stream
    self.address = address
    self.stream.read_bytes(23, self.first_data_handler)

tornado.iostream.IOStream.prepend_to_buffer = prepend_to_buffer
tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer.first_data_handler = first_data_handler
tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer.handle_stream = handle_stream
```